# Booking system in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I`m developing a booking system. I have 2 tables in the database:

```html
<table border=1><tr><td>booking</td><td>tables</td></tr>
<tr><td>id</td><td>id</td></tr>
<tr><td>booking_date</td><td>masa</td></tr>
<tr><td>booking_hour</td><td>status</td></tr>
<tr><td>booking_table</td><td>color</td></tr>
<tr><td>customer</td></tr>
```

What I tried to do is first select the date and hour when you want to book a table, then the tables will update their status based on the other reservations in the booking table. What I don`t know is how to verify the date and time chosen with the other bookings and update the tables.

```
$status='';
$result = mysqli_query($connector,"SELECT * from booking");
$result2 = mysqli_query($connector,"SELECT * from tables");


echo"
 <form method='post' action='booking.php' id=''>

<label>Choose a date:</label>
<p><input class='form-control' type='text' name='datepicker' id='datepicker'></p>
<label>Choose a period of time:</label> 
<select class='form-control form1' type='text' name='timepicker'>

<option value='810'>8:00-10:00</option>
<option value='1012'>10:00-12:00</option>
<option value='1214'>12:00-14:00</option>
<option value='1416'>14:00-16:00</option>
<option value='1618'>16:00-18:00</option>
<option value='1820'>18:00-20:00</option>
<option value='2022'>20:00-22:00</option>
</select>
<div class='btn-group' role='group' align='center'>
<table align='center'>
  <tr>";

  if(isset($datepicker) && isset($timepicker)){
   $count4 = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count4 == "0"){
  $output = '<h2>No result found!</h2>';
}else{


 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
if($count == "0"){
  $output = '<h2>No result found!</h2>';
}else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
  $status = $row['status'];
  $tableid = $row['masa'];
  $color = $row['color'];

if($tableid == 't1' ){                            
echo"<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' value='$status' name='t1' style='width:60px; height: 50px;margin:15px 5px 5px 0px;background-color:$color;font-size:9px'></td>";
}

if($tableid == 't2' ){
echo"<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' value='$status' name='t2' style='width:60px; height: 50px;margin:15px 5px 5px 0px;background-color:$color;font-size:9px'></td>";
}
```

UPDATE:
I managed to do it like so:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connector,"SELECT * from booking");
                  $result2 = mysqli_query($connector,"SELECT masa from tables");

                  $datepicker = $_POST['datepicker'];

                  $color='';
                  $busy=array();

                    echo"
                     <form method='post' action='booking.php' id=''>
                  ";




                      if(isset($datepicker)){


                         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


                    $booking=$row['booking_table'];
                    $date = $row['booking_date'];
                    $datecheck = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
                    if($datepicker == $datecheck){

                       array_push($busy,$row['booking_table']);
                       }

                    }







                    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){

                    $tableid=$row2['masa'];
                    if(in_array($tableid, $busy)){
                    $status='Booked';
                    $color='red';
                    $read='readonly';

                    }
                    else{
                      $status='Free';
                      $color='green';
                      $read='';
                    }



                    echo"<td width='50%'><input type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' value='$status' name='$tableid' style='width:60px; height: 50px;margin:15px 5px 5px 0px;background-color:$color;font-size:9px' $read></td>";



                    }





                }
```

Comment: 'Update their status based on the other reservations in the booking table'. Can you elaborate on this? Update what exactly, and on which conditions? Normally when you build a booking system, wouldn't you want to do continuous `INSERT` to leave the existing rows unaffected, so that you can keep track on previous bookings and perform statistic reports etc. etc. ? Update should be performed upon cancellations, and things like that?

Comment: When a user wants to book a table, he selects the day, the hour (i may remove this) and then the tables should appear underneath the 2 selectors with the status from the day selected ( some already booked, some free for example). I tried with insert but i`m not really sure how should i add them.

Comment: @GeorgeS What does the columns `status` and `color` mean in the `tables` table? And what is `masa`?

Comment: I use status to display text on the button - free/in progress/busy. Color is used to change the color of the button depending on status - green/yellow/red.
Masa means table and i use it as the table id.

Comment: @GeorgeS You cannot save the status and color in the `tables` table. The value depends on the reservation and the date/time you want to check. You have to calculate the status and color in your PHP script on-the-fly depending on the date/time the user has entered and the reservations which are already added to the `booking` table.

Comment: @Progman Thanks, that made me realise what i was doing wrong. I updated the code and now it seems to work fine.